Find all rows where a column is not equal to a specific value
I have the below table



id
fid
ts
val




401411341
3797
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
201902


401411616
3797
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
201902


401411848
3797
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
201902


401412147
3797
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
201902



I want to write a query to pull the id's that do not have fid = 3797?
Is this possible?
I can query for ids where it has fid=3797 but the val is NULL, but struggling to get a query to get the ids where it is missing the fid=3797 field all together.

Please add more sample rows, especially rows with other fid's, and also the expected result. Your question isn't clear yet.

SELECT id FROM (yourtable) WHERE fid <> 3797 ?

That's amazing, thanks @marc_s, I had no idea there was such a query!

The suggested query will work for the given data. But, can an id show up several times, with different fid values?

@jarlh Agree, at first glance, reading the text in the question without having a look on the sample data, I thought they need something like SELECT id FROM yourtable GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN fid <> '3797' THEN 1 END) = 0 And the sample data doesn't really help.

Nope id is distinct in this table * I should have mentioned

if fid can also contain null, then use select * from table where fid IS DISTINCT FROM 3797
